# A Basic Example of How to Use Material UI DatePicker

Tags: material-ui

I don't know why I can't wrap my head around how to use Material UI's DatePicker. It seems that the documentation is not complete? Am I correct?

Here is the basic example I have:

```
import {DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";

... somewhere in the render: 

            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <DatePicker
                    id="date"
                    value="2017-05-24"
                    allowKeyboardControl={false}
                    autoOk={true}
                />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

At first I got errors that 'n' something something wasn't working, and that is because either date-io or date-fns (the newer versions) wheren't supported. After downgrading.. I got told that the _onChange is not a function. I randomly thought that I could add an empty onChange={()=>{}} to get that error to go away and it did. Now I am noticing that when I actually select a date, the DatePicker date displayed on my page doesn't update to the new date.

So.. am I supposed to supply an onChange event? Why is that not clear anywhere?

Also, is the date supposed to be updating by default, or is my onChange supposed to do that?

**UPDATE:**
So.. it turns out this page that documents Material UI Pickers has a "View Code" icon under their examples (https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/).
So that shows how to handle the onChange. I wish it was more obvious in this documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `@date-io/date-fns` of v1.x
2. Pass required `onChange` callback:

```js
function BasicDatePicker(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <DatePicker
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Here [is working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7oojxx1pq?from-embed)